# How Can I add a Content Type to a Document Library using SPFx

Tags: content-type, spfx

I have a Content Type for a Document Library that resides in a Content Type Hub.  It's available on the team site.  Now when a Library is provisioned, I would like this content type to be added.  Can I do this with SPFx?  Anyone have an example to share?

Regards,
Bismarck